# Suma de posiciones de un ciclo for c

Tags: c

Hice un programa usando funciones en la cual solicita la edad de la persona, y añadí unas condiciones de que si es menor a 12 años es infantil y el costo es de 300, si es menor a 18 años se considera infantil y el costo es de 500 y si es mayor a 18 años se considera adulto y el costo es de 800. El programa permite el ingreso de 10 personas, sin embargo, no me esta sumando las posiciones que deseo para cada condición, yo lo que necesito es imprimir cuantas personas entraron en cada categoría pero no esta funcionando de la manera correcta. Disculpen si no me explique bien.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>    

void main ()
{
    int edad[10];
    int x,y,r;    

    printf ("BIENVENIDOS AL EVENTO\n");

    for (x=0;x<=9;x++) //Guarda 10 edades
    {
        printf ("Ingrese las edades");
        scanf (" %d",&edad[x]);
    }
    for (x=0;x<=9;x++)
    {
        printf (" %d",edad[x]);
    }    

     r=evento(edad);  //Llamando funcion
    printf ("El total de los boletos es de %d",r);
}

void evento (int edad[]) //Recibe funcion
{
    int suma=0, suma2=0, suma3=0;
    int i,o = 300,x,h = 500,t = 800,p,q;

    for (i=0; i < 10;i++) // Suma las posiciones que son menor a 13, aqui es donde no me esta dando, igual que en las otras condiciones. 

    {
        if (edad[i] < 13)   
        {
            suma = suma+i;
        }
    }
        printf ("En infantil ingresaron %d personas\n",suma);    

            for (i=0;i<10;i++)  // Suma las posiciones que son menor a 18
            {
                if (edad[i]<18)
                {
                    suma2 = suma2+i;
                }
            }
            printf ("En juvenil ingresaron %d personas\n",suma2);    

    for (i=0;i< 10;i++)   // Suma las posiciones que son mayor a 18 
            {
                if (edad[i]>18)
                {
                suma3=suma3+i;
                }
            }
            printf ("Ingresaron %d adultos\n",suma3);

    //q=h+o+t;
    //return q;
}
```

Comment: Hola Arturo, las categorías serían solo infantil, juvenil y adultos?

Comment: Así es, solamente son esas categorías

Comment: Hay una diferencia entre la suma de veces que aparece un elemento y la suma de las posiciones en que dicho elemento aparece. Dicho de otra forma: si solo hubiera un individuo infantil que estuviera en la posición 9 ¿qué devolvería tu código?

Comment: Aún no esta mi código completo, lo que voy a regresar es el total que voy a pagar de todos los boletos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

leyendo un poco creo que lo que necesitas es solo sumar la cantidad de personas por cada categoria y no los costos de cada boleto, entonces quedaria asi:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h> 



void main ()
{
    int edad[10];
    int x,r;



printf ("BIENVENIDOS AL EVENTO\n");

for (x=0;x<=9;x++) //Guarda 10 edades
{
    printf ("Ingrese las edades");
    scanf (" %d",&edad[x]);
}
for (x=0;x<=9;x++)
{
    printf (" %d",edad[x]);
}    

r=evento(edad);  //Llamando funcion
printf ("El total de los boletos es de %d",r);
}

void evento (int edad[]) //Recibe funcion
{
int sumas=0;
int sumas1=0;
int sumas2=0;
int j,k,q;

// con un solo ciclo recorremos todo el arreglo y discriminamos por categoria
    for (j=0; j < 10;j++) // Suma las posiciones que son menor a 13
    {
    if (edad[j] <13)   
    {
        sumas = sumas+1;
    }
    else 
    if (edad[j] >= 13 && edad[j]<18)
    {
        sumas1 = sumas1+1;//alamacenamos la suma de cada persona que son menor a 18

    }
    else
    if (edad[j]>18 )
    {
        sumas2 = sumas2+1;// alamacenamos la suma de cada persona que son mayor a 18
    }
}

printf ("En infantil ingresaron %d personas\n",sumas);    

printf ("En juvenil ingresaron %d personas\n",sumas1);    

printf ("En adultos ingresaron %d personas\n",sumas2);

q=1*k;
return q;
}
```

**NOTA** si quieres sumar los valores de cada boleto, tambien seria de la misma forma...

espero te sirva y la marques xD... ReNiceCode...

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81444/discussion-on-answer-by-srjj-suma-de-posiciones-de-un-ciclo-for-c).

Comment: ok maestro, lo tuve en mente, pero creo que aun no tengo privilegios de crear un chat

Comment: Qué es eso de ReNiceCode?

Comment: Es un gerga con el "Re" de mucho mas "Nice" bonito "Code" codigo, (es algo mio, es como decir "Te Deseo buenos Codigo)

Comment: Disculpa yo igual no tenía privilegios de crear un chat